# UIButton imageView - after UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill how to move the image up?

Tags: ios, uibutton, imageview, aspect-ratio

I want to capture a picture using camera according to my guideline. When I saved it into a button and do the aspect ratio, the image focuses onto the middle part of the image. This would have been fine have I centered the guideline. But I want the guideline to be higher. Thus, I would like to move the image lower. Here is the code

```
[personPhotoButton setImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[personPhotoButton imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```

I like the image in the button move down to show the upper potion of the image.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do that by changing the `imageEdgeInsets` of `UIButton`.

Let me know if that works..